# Transfer large scanned files from copier to computer

Tags: scanner, data-transfer

Our office has a Konica Bizhub C452 copier which has high resolution scanning.

Unfortunately, it is impossible to use the high-resolution scanning because it sends the file via email and our email server blocks transfers over a certain limit, which any high resolution document scan will usually exceed.

Is there any other way to get the data off the copier and to a computer?

(Note that this model of Bizhub does not have a USB port.)

Comment: Configure a local smtp server, and receive the emails locally as large as you want.

Comment: @IporSircer I need to sell this to IT, and my guess is that they will not want to install an entire SMTP server just to service the copier.

Comment: install smtp is a oneliner command. Installing a correct driver for mouse is a more difficult operation. Can't you configure the scanner to store the files locally and don't try to sent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [bizhub C452 specifications](https://www.konicaminolta.fr/fr/solutions-dentreprise/produits-et-applications/systemes-dimpression-office/multifonctions/produits-arretes-couleur/business-hub-c452/specifications.html),
this printer has alternative methods for transmitting scans.

Scan-to-SMB : Scan to a folder on a networked computer.
Scan-to-FTP : Scan to an FTP server.

Multiple scan setups can be registered and named for multiple users.

See for example this youtube tutorial how to set it up :
[Add Scan to Shared Folder (SMB)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNA_cREfpzQ).

Comment: Thanks for the idea. One hitch I ran into was that the copier was asking for username and password. The folder I wanted to sent to is a public share. When I tried leaving uname/pw blank it gave a "logon" error. Why do I need to give the copier my credentials if the folder is a public share?

Comment: See [How to Turn On or Off Public Folder Sharing in Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/50179-public-folder-sharing-turn-off-windows-10-a.html).